# proftpd fails on boot saying "MasqueradeAddress: unable to resolve rowilson.dyndns.org"

Tags: linux, boot, debian, ftp

I have proftpd set up on my linux home server. As I have a dynamic IP at home, I am using DynDns.org to provide a hostname for me. I have told proftpd to use this address as the MasqueradeAddress, to allow passive FTP connections through my NAT router.

However, whenever I boot my server, proftpd fails to start saying it cannot resolve this address. I assume this is due to the boot order, as something network or DNS related hasn't started up by then and it can't find the address.

How should I deal with this problem? Can I get proftpd to do its checking for the address later on? Or can I change the startup order so that proftpd is started as the final item in the boot sequence?

Comment: For me, in British Columbia, Canada, I can resolve that hostname to 87.112.134.193 although it doesn't respond to ICMP (initiated by the "ping" utility).

Comment: Having the exact same issue right now, in 2018. I assumed we need to start the FTP server as one of the last tasks during the boot process. For this, I tinkered around with `/etc/rc.local`, without success. Then I realized. SFTP works over SSH. I don't even need proftpd anymore. I can just enable SSH, and with the same credentials, I can use SFTP. And it's more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/resolv.conf file, and make sure it specifies your router's internal IP address (probably the same as your gateway since you're using NAT).